# Setting the LastPasswordSet date for a user in Active Directory

Tags: .net, active-directory, adsi, lastpasswordset

I want to set the `LastPasswordSet` attribute of a user in Microsoft Active Directory.

The .NET `UserPrincipal` API  exposes the `LastPasswordSet` property as readonly.

Is there a way around this, to set the value (perhaps using ADSI)?

**Edit:**

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms180915.aspx) provides the following example code:

```
usr.Properties["pwdLastSet"].Value = -1; // To turn on, set this value to 0.
usr.CommitChanges();
```

This forces the user to change their password at next logon. I presume if I replace -1 with a date-time in the relevant format, this will do what I want.

It does not, however, show how I get hold of the principal (presumably `usr`). I'll upvote anything that helps me find this out.

Comment: http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2005/07/06/how-can-i-cause-a-user-s-password-to-expire.aspx - may be of use

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms180915.aspx - may also be of use

Comment: Ok, I understand your intent now. You should post the relevant portion of the second link as an answer so I can upvote it and you can accept it. pretend I said nothing... ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way would be to perform a search against the AD through the [`DirectorySearcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher.aspx) class using the login of your users.

```
public DirectoryEntry GetUser(string domain, string loginName) {
    DirectorySearcher ds = new DirectorySearcher();
    ds.SearchRoot = new DirectoryEntry(domain);
    ds.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
    ds.PropertiesToLoad.Add("sAMAccountName");
    ds.PropertiesToLoad.Add("pwdLastSet");
    ds.Filter = string.Format("(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName={0})", loginName);

    SearchResult sr = null;

    try {
        sr = ds.FindOne();
        if (sr == null) return null;
        return sr.GetDirectoryEntry();
    } catch (Exception) {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Then, when wanting to set your `PasswordLastSet` property, you assure that the user exists and that there is no spelling mistakes.

```
string loginName = "AstonB1";

using(DirectoryEntry user = GetUser(loginName)) {
    if (user == null) return;

    user.Properties["pwdLastSet"].Value = whatever-format-the-date-should-be;
    user.CommitChanges();
    user.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
var usr = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://CN=Old User,CN=users,DC=fabrikam,DC=com");
usr.Properties["pwdLastSet"].Value = whatever-format-the-date-should-be;
usr.CommitChanges();
```

As yet untested.